# FromBluetoothAddressAsync function return null

Tags: windows-runtime, bluetooth-lowenergy

Sometimes FromBluetoothAddressAsync() from WinRT returns NULL:

```
BluetoothLEDevice::FromBluetoothAddressAsync(deviceAddr).get();
```

Thats depends by deviceAddr, thats mean that function for some of remote devices everytime returns NULL, for some of devices return BluetoothLEDevice object.

Somewhere in the Internet, I found a mention that this is a Microsoft problem and nothing can be done about it, but that was a few years ago. Therefore, the question to those who often use this function is: what kind of devices cannot receive BluetoothLEDevice object and how to proceed in this case?

GetFirstAdvertisingBLEAddr():

```
uint64_t GetFirstAdvertisingBLEAddr()
{
    std::mutex m;
    std::condition_variable cv;

    BluetoothLEAdvertisementWatcher advWatcher;
    uint64_t addr = 0;
    bool stopCalled = false;
    auto recvToken = advWatcher.Received([&addr, &m, &cv](BluetoothLEAdvertisementWatcher watcher, BluetoothLEAdvertisementReceivedEventArgs eventArgs) {
        ShowAdvertisement(eventArgs);
        addr = eventArgs.BluetoothAddress();
        watcher.Stop();
        std::unique_lock l(m);
        cv.notify_all(); 
    });
    auto stoppedToken = advWatcher.Stopped([&stopCalled, &m, &cv](BluetoothLEAdvertisementWatcher watcher, BluetoothLEAdvertisementWatcherStoppedEventArgs eventArgs) {
        std::unique_lock l(m);
        stopCalled = true;
        cv.notify_all();
    });

    {
        std::unique_lock l(m);
        advWatcher.Start();
        cv.wait(l, [&addr, &stopCalled, &advWatcher] { return addr != 0 && stopCalled && (advWatcher.Status() == BluetoothLEAdvertisementWatcherStatus::Aborted || advWatcher.Status() == BluetoothLEAdvertisementWatcherStatus::Stopped); });
    }

    // remove event handlers
    advWatcher.Received(recvToken);
    advWatcher.Stopped(stoppedToken);

    return addr;
}
```

GetDeviceName():

```
std::wstring GetDeviceName(uint64_t deviceAddr) {
BluetoothLEDevice dev = BluetoothLEDevice::FromBluetoothAddressAsync(deviceAddr).get();
if (NULL == dev) {
    std::wstringstream resp;
    resp << L"NULL" << AddrToString(deviceAddr);
    return resp.str();
}
auto gapServicesResult = dev.GetGattServicesForUuidAsync(GattServiceUuids::GenericAccess(), BluetoothCacheMode::Uncached).get();
if (gapServicesResult.Status() == GattCommunicationStatus::Success) {
    auto gapServices = gapServicesResult.Services();
    if (gapServices.Size() > 0) {
        GattDeviceService genericAccessSvc = gapServices.GetAt(0);
        if (genericAccessSvc) {
            auto gapDeviceNameChrs = genericAccessSvc.GetCharacteristics(GattCharacteristicUuids::GapDeviceName());
            if (gapDeviceNameChrs.Size() == 1) {
                GattCharacteristic gapDeviceNameChr = gapDeviceNameChrs.GetAt(0);

                GattReadResult readRes = gapDeviceNameChr.ReadValueAsync().get();
                if (readRes.Status() == GattCommunicationStatus::Success) {
                    DataReader reader = DataReader::FromBuffer(readRes.Value());
                    return reader.ReadString(reader.UnconsumedBufferLength()).c_str();
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

main():

```
int main()
{

    winrt::init_apartment();

    std::wcout << "Main thread: " << std::this_thread::get_id() << std::endl;

    uint64_t addr = GetFirstAdvertisingBLEAddr();
    if (addr == 0) {
        std::wcout << L"Failed to find advertising BLE device." << std::endl;
        return 1;
    }
    std::wcout << "Found BLE device: " << GetDeviceName(addr) << std::endl;

    BluetoothLEDevice dev = BluetoothLEDevice::FromBluetoothAddressAsync(addr).get();

    GattDeviceServicesResult result = dev.GetGattServicesAsync(BluetoothCacheMode::Uncached).get();
.......
```

Comment: The device must ne discovered somehow before calling this method. Its better to use AdvertisementWatcher instead of DeviceWatcher.

Comment: Device was discowered. I added code to post, if you will have any advices,please tell me.

Comment: You did not analize advertisement frames. You have to wait when frame with connectable flag will be received.

Comment: Can you show me how to do that?

Comment: Just parse advertisement data and check flags for Connectable one.